# Running Project on Tomcat Through Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

I have a project file that I am trying to run through eclipse on tomcat. Right now the server starts up, but when I try to access the server (with localhost:8080), I get a 404 error. Looking at the server console found in Eclipse, I am seeing some weird messages and was hoping that one of you could make sense of them. The messages are below. Thanks!

**INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;;.**

**WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ROOT' did not find a matching property.**

**INFO: JSR 356 WebSocket (Java WebSocket 1.0) support is not available when running on Java 6. To suppress this message, run Tomcat on Java 7, remove the WebSocket JARs from $CATALINA_HOME/lib or add the WebSocket JARs to the tomcat.util.scan.DefaultJarScanner.jarsToSkip property in $CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties. Note that the deprecated Tomcat 7 WebSocket API will be available.**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Tomcat starts properly.

The messages you get:

> INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path

This just means you don't have a native library which would make Tomcat run even faster. No worries.

> WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ROOT' did not find a matching property.

This means that in the `server.xml` file of your Tomcat the `<Context>` element contains a `source` attribute and Tomcat can't/won't handle it so it will be ignored.

> INFO: JSR 356 WebSocket (Java WebSocket 1.0) support is not available when running on Java 6.

This just means WebSocket is not available/not supported under Tomcat 6. No worries.